# How to fix System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net

EDIT: This issue is resolved, good thanks to Reniuz for his 5 hours of work and research of this issue, thank's everyone.

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on the following code and I've searched and searched and pulled my hair out for over 7-8 hours now trying to fix it.

```
private void buttonAddEffect_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EffectSelectorForm effectSelectorForm = new EffectSelectorForm(Effects);
    if (effectSelectorForm.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        // create a new instance of the selected effect as we may want multiple copies of one effect
        Effect effect = (Effect)Activator.CreateInstance(effectSelectorForm.SelectedEffect.GetType());
        audioGraph.AddEffect(effect);
        int index = checkedListBox1.Items.Add(effect, true);
        checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
    }
    //MessageBox.Show(String.Format("I have {0} effects", Effects.Count));
}
```

Error is on the line:
EffectSelectorForm effectSelectorForm = new EffectSelectorForm(Effects);

the class:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication13
{
    public partial class EffectSelectorForm : Form
    {
        public EffectSelectorForm(ICollection<Effect> effects)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBoxEffects.DisplayMember = "Name";
            listBoxEffects.DataSource = effects;
        }

        private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
        }

        public Effect SelectedEffect
        {
            get
            {
                return (Effect)listBoxEffects.SelectedItem;
            }
        }

        private void listBoxEffects_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            buttonOK_Click(sender, e);
        }
```

What this is supposed to do is when the effectSelectorForm loads it should make a list of all the voice changer options but it does not do that.... it loads nothing on it, I got this code from another form for changing voice in Skype and re-wrote about 400 lines of code for it to work in my app but now I have this issue and I'm not giving up with all the effort I've put in so far. If it loaded on the other project why not in this one? I've went over code for hours over and over thinking im missing something but no.

Any help would be fantastic.

Stack

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at WindowsFormsApplication13.pwn4g3.buttonAddEffect_Click_1(Object sender, EventArgs e) in F:\Users\Tom\Desktop\New folder\New folder (2)\TestApp\pwn4g3\PWN4G3\MainForm2.cs:line 1758
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Effect.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace JSNet
{    

    public abstract class Effect
    {
        private List<Slider> sliders;
        public float SampleRate { get; set; }
        public float Tempo { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }

        public Effect()
        {
            sliders = new List<Slider>();
            Enabled = true;
            Tempo = 120;
            SampleRate = 44100;
        }

        public IList<Slider> Sliders { get { return sliders; } }

        public Slider AddSlider(float defaultValue, float minimum, float maximum, float increment, string description)
        {
            Slider slider = new Slider(defaultValue, minimum, maximum, increment, description);
            sliders.Add(slider);
            return slider;
        }

        public abstract string Name { get; }

        // helper base methods
        // these are primarily to enable derived classes to use a similar
        // syntax to JS effects
        protected float slider1 { get { return sliders[0].Value; } }
        protected float slider2 { get { return sliders[1].Value; } }
        protected float slider3 { get { return sliders[2].Value; } }
        protected float slider4 { get { return sliders[3].Value; } }
        protected float slider5 { get { return sliders[4].Value; } }
        protected float slider6 { get { return sliders[5].Value; } }
        protected float slider7 { get { return sliders[6].Value; } }
        protected float slider8 { get { return sliders[7].Value; } }
        protected float min(float a, float b) { return Math.Min(a, b); }
        protected float max(float a, float b) { return Math.Max(a, b); }
        protected float abs(float a) { return Math.Abs(a); }
        protected float exp(float a) { return (float)Math.Exp(a); }
        protected float sqrt(float a) { return (float)Math.Sqrt(a); }
        protected float sin(float a) { return (float)Math.Sin(a); }
        protected float tan(float a) { return (float)Math.Tan(a); }
        protected float cos(float a) { return (float)Math.Cos(a); }
        protected float pow(float a, float b) { return (float)Math.Pow(a, b); }
        protected float sign(float a) { return Math.Sign(a); }
        protected float log(float a) { return (float)Math.Log(a); }
        protected float PI { get { return (float)Math.PI; } }

        protected void convolve_c(float[] buffer1, int offset1, float[] buffer2, int offset2, int count)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count * 2; i += 2)
            {
                float r = buffer1[offset1 + i];
                float im = buffer1[offset1 + i + 1];
                float cr = buffer2[offset2 + i];
                float ci = buffer2[offset2 + i + 1];
                buffer1[offset1 + i] = r * cr - im * ci;
                buffer1[offset1 + i + 1] = r * ci + im * cr;
            }
        }


        public virtual void Init()
        {
        }


        public abstract void Slider();


        public virtual void Block(int samplesblock)
        { 
        }


        public abstract void Sample(ref float spl0, ref float spl1);

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The stack trace would be helpful. Are you sure there are not fields in Effect that are null that when the DataSource is set and processed are causing the null?

Comment: > Stack trace added, and it's if I press okay I get the error, but I guess it's because their is nothing in the listbox and its returning null.. in that case I need to find why their is nothing in the list.

Comment: cant you debug and see what do you have in Effects variable, which is passed to form?

Comment: Is Effects declared properly?

Comment: That line should not throw a `NullReferenceException`. If `Effects` is null, it should throw an `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: @KendallFrey You can set a DataSource to null. It's legal from what I remember. It should never throw ArgumentNullException when setting DataSource.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell: I was assuming the error was on `EffectSelectorForm effectSelectorForm = new EffectSelectorForm(Effects);`

Comment: Can you show your Effect class?

Comment: 1. Are you running a Debug build or a Release build? 2. Did you start the app under the debugger, attach the debugger after the app was already running, or get a stack trace independent of the debugger (e.g. by `catch`ing the exception and logging its stack trace)? If the answers are anything other than "Debug build" and "started under the debugger", then the compiler and/or JITter might be optimizing and/or inlining some methods, and the stack trace could be misleading.

Comment: The line in question refers to a property called `Effect`. Could you show us the property's implementation? It's possible that the exception is happening in the property getter.

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is 100% here

```
EffectSelectorForm effectSelectorForm = new EffectSelectorForm(Effects);
```

There's only one possible explanation: property/variable "Effects" is not initialized properly... Debug your code to see what you pass to your objects.

**EDIT** after several hours

There were some problems:

- MEF attribute [Import] didn't work as expected, so we replaced it for the time being with a manually populated List<>. While the collection was null, it was causing exceptions later in the code, when the method tried to get the type of the selected item and there was none.
- several event handlers weren't wired up to control events

Some problems are still present, but I believe OP's original problem has been fixed. Other problems are not related to this one.

Comment: It has to do with the objects in that list. Because you can set a DataSource to null just fine. If Effects was null it would just be an empty list and he wouldnt be able to select anything. So it has to be the objects in this list. Sometimes the magic in .NET is great, other times it makes debugging impossible.

Comment: I think it because I'm pressing okay when it's null.. and like I said if that's the issue then I am still jammed on the issue that I cannot get it to load effects. Sorry I'm a little new to this. I did debug and not sure how it helps to find error.

Comment: @AndrewFinell it does debug, yes.. but once I open that listbox and press okay it break's debugging now.. And I understand why, because it's null.. But now I need to work on why the listbox is not having content added to it.

Comment: @iKonroi I really suggest you to read this article: [Mastering Debugging](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn)

Comment: @AndrewFinnell, yes, that's true. However, by saying "not initialized properly" I meant it somewhat more general, not necessarily that the list itself is null.

Comment: Not sure how that helps me find why it will not load my list... but loads in the other app :x.

Comment: @iKonroi, let the program to write down the list the old way if you have problems with debugging - use foreach loop. Don't bind it to any control yet, just look what's inside, what properties, what objects, what values...

Comment: Ehh.. I really wish I understood that better. Not even sure how a for each loop would help in any bit, does anyone have Skype? and / or Team Viewer, I would really like to get some sleep been up for around 40 hours on this project. And stuck for last 8.

Comment: @iKonroi could you add your Effect class to question?

Comment: @iKonroi, of course, I have both, just wondering how to pass them to you without giving them to the whole world :) I'll put my skype ID to my profile info here and it will stay there for next 10minutes if you want to contact me.

Comment: @Reniuz - Added it, and walther my Skype is i.Konroi

Answer (score 0):

During debug, break on all exceptions thrown.
Debug->Exceptions

Check all 'Thrown' exceptions. F5, the code will stop on the offending line.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it only occurred on the published website on Godaddy.
It was no problem in my local host.

The error came from an aspx.cs (code behind file) where I tried to assign a value to a label.
It appeared that from within the code behind, that the label Text appears to be  null.
So all I did with change all my Label Text properties in the ASPX file from Text=""   to Text=" ".

The problem disappeared.  I don’t know why the error happens from the hosted version but not on my localhost and don’t have time to figure out why.  But it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error, but for me this was due to a method in a base class (in Project A) having the output type changed from a non-void type to void.  A child class existed in Project B (which I didn't want used and had marked obsolete) that I missed when performing this update and hence started throwing this error.

> 1>CSC : error CS8104: An error occurred while writing the output file: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Original Code:

```
[Obsolete("Calling this method will throw an error")]
public override CompletionStatus Run()
{
    throw new CustomException("Run process not supported.");
}
```

Revised Code:

```
[Obsolete("Calling this method will throw an error")]
public override void Run()
{
    throw new CustomException("Run process not supported.");
}
```